# How to create multiple Uglify tasks in grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am using `Grunt` and `grunt-contrib-uglify` plugin to minify the JavaScript files in my project.

The JS files are spread across multiple directories under `src` directory. My aim is to move them to the appropriate directories under `build` directory.

**My current structure**

```
src
  - app
    - page
      - page1
        -page1.js
      - page2
        -page2.js

    - components
      -header
        - header.js
      -footer   
         - footer.js
```

**My aim is to get to below structure**

```
build
  - app
    - page
      - page1 
        -page1.min.js
      - page2 
        -page2.min.js

    - components
      -header 
        - header.min.js
      -footer 
        - footer.min.js
```

I have tried with this task so far:

```
uglify: {
       my_target: {
         files: [
         {
             expand: true,
             cwd: 'src/app/components/**',
             src: '**/*.js',
             dest: 'build/app/components/**',
              ext:'.min.js'
         },
         {
             expand: true,
             cwd: 'src/app/page/**',
             src: '**/*.js',
             dest: 'build/app/page/**',
              ext:'.min.js'
         }
        ]
       }
     }
```

I am unable to get this to work. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**Note:**: The folder names are dynamic and I cannot hard code them in my tasks.